# Paging in Ext Grid

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs, pagination

Hi I am using Ext Js version 4.1.8 and I want to add paging on my extjs grid.

I have been using

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'List',    
    proxy:{
       type: 'ajax',
       api:{
           read:'getJson.php',
       },
       extraParams:{
           PRKEY : selectedProjId
       },
    },
    reader:{
       type: 'json',
       root: 'data',    
    }
});
```

That is working fine, but if I change my json format in my php file and change the root type to someother string like 'users' I do not see any data

Here is my json creation code in getJson.php

```
//in a loop
$aNode = array( 
    "Name" => "My Name",
    "ID"   => "123");
array_push($nodeArr, $aNode);
//end of loop

$json = new Services_JSON;
echo $json->encode($nodeArr);
```

and here is for the php code I want to run

```
//in a loop
$aNode = array( 
"Name" => "My Name",
    "ID"   => "123");
array_push($nodeArr, $aNode);
//end of loop

$json = new Services_JSON;
$jsonResult = array(
    'success' => "true",
    'users' => $nodeArr
);
echo $json->encode($jsonResult );
```

and here is the new store code

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'List',  
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        api:{
            read:'getJson.php',
        },
        extraParams:{
            PRKEY :selectedProjId
        },
    },
    reader:{
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users'
    }
});
```

Please help so I can add totalProperty in reader of my store and perform paging.

Comment: Did you change your store definition to  `reader: { type:'json', root: 'users' }` ?

Comment: yes, that was the older store sample that was working, I will paste the new one wait

Comment: @Fahrad you got `root: 'tasks'` in store and you are sending array with key `'users'` thats why you have no data

Comment: @szapio I am sorry that was a typo in my question I am using 'users' in my code

Comment: Now with this changes it should work. Did you get it to work?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer no its not working, thats why I am confused

Answer (score 0):

Add the value of totalProperty adjacent to success, for example:

```
$total = get_total_number_of_records();
$jsonResult = array(
    'success' => "true",
    'total' => $total
    'users' => $nodeArr
);
```

Server side has to honor sent `start` and `limit` parameters in addition to `total` and it has to return only `limit` number of records starting from `start`, not all from the database.

Comment: What exactly mean "no success"? What happened in contrary to your expectations? Error messages?

Answer (score 0):

ahh figured it out guys.
I was using 'reader' outside proxy block. I changed it and added it inside proxy and it worked.

Cheers! here is how it works

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'List',  
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        api:{
            read:'getJson.php',
        },
        extraParams:{
            PRKEY :selectedProjId
        },
        reader:{
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }        
});
```